# How to use imported DropDown widget's values in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, localization, widget

I'm new to Flutter and I'm working on a localization feature using the *easy_localizations* package. I created a dropdown that shows languages you can switch to and it works perfectly fine when the dropdown is directly on the page. But since it will be on every page, I want to have the dropdown as a custom widget instead, and then just import it on the pages, like this:

```
const Padding(
        padding: xPadding25, 
        child: DropDown(),
        ),
```

However, that does not work. I'm still able to click on the dropdown and choose a language, but it doesn't translate the pages anymore. I think it has to do something with the context it's translating, but I don't know how to make it so that it will take context of the pages and not its own if it makes sense.

Here's the code for the DropDown widget:

```
class DropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDown({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropDown> createState() => _DropDownState();
}

String dropdownValue = 'English';

class _DropDownState extends State<DropDown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (DropdownButton<String>(
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.language,
        color: scTealColor,
      ),
      value: dropdownValue,
      elevation: 16,
      style: smBodyStyle,
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: scTealColor,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue ?? "";
          if (dropdownValue == 'French') {
            context.setLocale(const Locale('fr'));
          } else {
            context.setLocale(const Locale('en'));
          }
        });
      },
      items: <String>['English', 'French']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ));
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to implement it so that the translation works when imported to pages as a custom widget? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to pass context into your dropdown class ? for i.e.,

```
const Padding(
        padding: xPadding25, 
        child: DropDown(context),
        ),
```